# What is the cardinality of the set of all ultrafilters containing a Fréchet filter?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, filters

Let $\mathfrak{F}$ be the Fréchet filter on an infinite set $X$. $~$What is the cardinality of the set of all ultrafilters containing $\mathfrak{F}\,$? $~$Is it equal to the cardinality $2^{2^{|X|}}$ of the set of *all* ultrafilters on the set $X\,$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. If an ultrafilter $U$ does not contain the Fréchet filter, then $U$ must be principal. A principal ultrafilter is determined by its generating element, so there are $|X|$-many principal ultrafilters. Since $|X|<2^{2^{|X|}}$, the cardinality of the set of non-principal ultrafilters must be $2^{2^{|X|}}$.

Comment: Beat me to it. I think your explanation is better anyway.

Comment: I don't know about that - I thought our answer were basically the same, and I liked that yours explained why ultrafilters not containing the Frechet filter have to be principal. @KyleGannon

Comment: @Alex Kruckman Short and sweet.